# How to start playing song from FileManager

Tags: swift

I have code that can download song in my fileManager system, how can I play it in AVPlayer? I tried to use AVPlayer(url: destinationUrl), but it does not work

```
func downloadTrack(url: String, completion: @escaping (URL) -> ())  {

        if let audioUrl = URL(string: url) {

            // then lets create your document folder url
            let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

            // lets create your destination file url
            let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(audioUrl.lastPathComponent)
            print(destinationUrl)

            // to check if it exists before downloading it
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationUrl.path) {
                print("The file already exists at path")
                completion(destinationUrl)
            } else {

                // you can use NSURLSession.sharedSession to download the data asynchronously
                URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: audioUrl, completionHandler: { (location, response, error) -> Void in
                    guard let location = location, error == nil else { return }
                    do {
                        // after downloading your file you need to move it to your destination url
                        try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationUrl)
                        print("File moved to documents folder")
                        completion(destinationUrl)
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }).resume()
            }
        }
    }
```

```
audioDownloader.downloadTrack(url: urlString) { url in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
                    self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
                    self.player.play()
                    self.player.volume = 1.0
                    self.player.rate = 1.0
                }
            }
```

AVPlayer is not nil, iOS version is 13.6

Comment: Is the line `print("File moved to documents folder")` reached and printed? Where's your code that attempt to play the save file? Add that to your question. Are you sure the code to play the save audio file is being called after the file is actually fully downloaded?

Comment: line print("File moved to documents folder") reached and printed

Comment: Have you confirmed that `playerItem` isn't `nil`? What version of iOS are you testing with? You might need to ensure you run the `AVPlayer` code on the main queue.

Comment: Two notes: 1) You have to call the completion handler if the file already exists. 2) Ignoring a potential error of  `downloadTask` is bad practice.

Comment: updated:
1) call completion if exist
2) playeitem is not nil
3) version 13.6

Comment: I call it from DispatchQueue.main.async, check my post pls, i updated it. I also tried to set DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(destinationUrl) }, nothing happens :(